# How I can encode JSON with multiple elements in Go Lang

Tags: json, go

I need consultation or sample code how I can send to customer multiple elements in JSON. Thank you!

I need next JSON structure:

```
{{"id":123,"first_name":"Demo","last_name":"User","time":"2017-07-03T16:36:41.4101847Z","count":1,"payout":"839`"},{"id":124,"first_name":"Demo","last_name":"User1","time":"2017-07-03T16:36:41.4101847Z","count":1,"payout":"839`"},{"id":125,"first_name":"Demo","last_name":"User2","time":"2017-07-03T16:36:41.4101847Z","count":1,"payout":"839`"}}
```

Comment: That JSON object is invalid.

Comment: If you want consultation or example code, try the documentation. If you have tried to implement something and you're running into a problem, post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"
)

type Elememt struct {
    ID int `json:"id"`
    FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
    LastName string `json:"last_name"`
    Time time.Time `json:"time"`
    Count int `json:"count"`
    Payout string `json:"payout"`
}

func main() {
    elements := []Elememt {
        {
            ID: 1,
            FirstName: "Dmitriy",
            LastName: "Groschovskiy",
            Time: time.Now(),
            Count: 1,
            Payout: "200",
        },
        {
            ID: 2,
            FirstName: "Yasuhiro",
            LastName: "Matsumoto",
            Time: time.Now(),
            Count: 2,
            Payout: "150",
        },
    }

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    err := json.NewEncoder(&buf).Encode(elements)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://httpbin.org/post", &buf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    io.Copy(os.Stdout, resp.Body)
}
```

Comment: I find myself wondering if we should advocate for less hand-holding in the go tagged questions... At the same time though, I would rather see more adoption of the language. Tough call.